# SwiftLint native rule with custom path

Tags: swift, swiftlint

How can I apply the native `file_name` SwiftLint rule specifically to test files (files ending with `test` or `tests` in their name)?

Comment: Use multiple config files maybe: https://github.com/bulldozair/mobile-ios/issues/622 ?

Comment: you can try linting those files over the terminal like below `swiftlint lint path/to/MyFileTest.swift`  But the output will be visible on the terminal using the above command. Hope it helps.